# Como fazer para após o usuário usar o input não quebrar linha

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Acontece que eu quero usar um input, ou seja colocar um valor mas após apertar enter não quebrar a linha mas continuar no lugar onde escrevi o valor, não tenho uma ideia de como fazer com o input do python, eu tentei fazer isso:

```
a = input("", end="")
```

mas dá o seguinte erro

```
"input() takes no keyword arguments".
```

Bom o código que estou pensando em fazer é sobre colocar a data no formato DD/MM/AAAA.
Só que toda vez que se usa input() você aperta enter quando coloca o valor, tipo 20, o cursor vai para a linha de baixo para escrever outra coisa caso se colocar outro input, mas eu quero que ele continua na mesma linha que eu coloco a data 20, para depois eu por uma / para aparecer e dai colocar 05 do mês por exemplo.

Bem é isso, obrigado!

Comment: Poderia editar a pergunta e colocar o código ?

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Você quer que o enter que o usuário dá para colocar o input não quebre a linha é isso ? Se for isso não me parece que seja possível, pelo menos em consola.

Comment: Isso mesmo, bom então parece que devo deletar a pergunta. Mas obrigado mesmo.

Comment: O ideal será aguardar pelo *feedback* de outras pessoas da comunidade. Talvez alguém conheça uma forma de contornar, ou talvez confirmem o que eu disse.

Comment: Certo, vou esperar, será que em outra linguagem isso seja possível?

Comment: Ola @LucasFariasRodrigues como está? Espero que goste do Stack Overflow. Para a sua resposta, pode usar o [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173850/possible-to-get-user-input-without-inserting-a-new-line), está em inglês, porem é a sua solução. Se tiver dificuldades, comente, que eu posto uma resposta.

Comment: Olá, estou bem, e você? Bem, eu li as respostas, tentei algumas e elas não funcionaram a do getpass por exemplo, parece que a que funciona é última do ForgottenUmbrella mas sinceramente não achei fácil de entender como aplicá-la(comecei a estudar tem uma semana), mas vou continuar tentando com o tempo, mas muito obrigado mesmo, algum dia vou conseguir aplicar ela.

Comment: Não apague a pergunta- ela é uma dúvid a legítima - só não tem uma resposta simples!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isso não funciona assim no terminal.

### Segue História Resumida da Entrada e Saída em Programação

A ideia de aprender "print" e "input" primeiro quando estamos aprendendo a programar, ou uma nova linguagem, é que são os métodos de entrada e saída mais fáceis embutidos na linguagem para comunicação com o usuário.

No entanto, ambas as funções remetem a um tempo da computação em que monitores de vídeo não eram de uso tão comum - o computador tinha uma impressora de texto, linha a linha, e um teclado - o terminal "emula" a impressão de um relatório em papel imprimindo linha após linha. Isso é feito no sistema operacional, que disponibiliza para os programas uma "entrada padrão", uma "saída padrão" e uma "saída padrão de erros" - ainda hoje, grande parte dos programas de linha de comando funcionaria se a "saída padrão" fosse uma impressora de linha, em vez de uma janela de terminal.

O 'print' continua imprimindo linha após linha - o que acontece é que em linguagens como Python, ele tem formas sofisticadas de elaborar uma string antes de envia-la ao terminal.

Já o input, ele emula a entrada pelo terminal - o usuário digitava uma linha de texto (ou perfurava um cartão), e ao apertar "enter" (ou colocar o cartão), os dados da linha eram entrados todos de uma vez.

Existem sim formas de se usar o termina de forma "randômica", podendo imprimir carácteres em qualquer lugar na tela, ler teclas pressionadas sem aguardar o "enter", ou não ecoar o "enter" para o terminal, evitando a quebra de linha. Essas formas também foram criadas lá atrás - logo que puseram os terminais de vídeo, mas por algum motivo, **nunca se tornaram a forma padrão de uso do terminal**. Algumas linguagens de programação das antigonas optaram por integrar esse uso sofisticado do terminal direto na linguagem - por exemplo, o Cobol - mas isso implica em que a linguagem de programação se "fixa" em um nicho, sempre "contando com um terminal de acesso randômico". Linguagens de uso genérico como as da família do C, Java, Python não tem nenhuma preferência por um tipo de entrada e saída mais sofisticado que 'saída padrão' e 'entrada padrão' no nível da linguagem - embora sejam flexíveis para você poder usar uma biblioteca para qualquer tipo de entrada e saída: um porgrama que usa uma janela própria, um programa web, uma tela gráfica livre, como a de um jogo, ou uma conexão customizada com dispositivos de E/S distintos, como webcans, microfones, alto-falantes E até mesmo, um terminal randômico, com acesso "fora de ordem". Só que nenhuma dessas formas de E/S está vinculada as funções comuns "print" e "input" (ou equivalentes em outras linguagens).

Para os seus usuários é muito melhor fazer isso do que tentar re-inventar a roda no terminal, deixando-o "mais fácil de usar": para usuários modernos, se não estão acostumados com o terminal, por mais "chique" que esteja seu programa no terminal, ele vai continuar sendo alienígena. Para usuários modernos acostumados com o terminal (Desenvolvedores, admin, etc...), um programa de terminal que fuja das convenções de entrada e saída linha a linha **também** será algo alienígena.

## O que fazer?

- **desenvolvimento web**

Se você quer qualquer entrada e saída mais sofisticada do que o print e input linha a linha, a melhor coisa é *mudar* o sistema de entrada e saída do seu programa, e torna-lo ou um programa gráfico com janela própria, ou um programa Web - nesse caso, a "entrada e saída" padrão dele são conectadas ao protocolo HTTP, e o programa gera uma página HTML, com formulários e CSS, que é exibida pelo navegador Web - isso pode ser feito mesmo se o programa for local: o navegador aponta para o próprio computador onde o programa está rodando.

É todo um paradigma diferente, é um sistema muito mais complexo do que o mecanismo de "input" e "print" que aprendemos primeiro, envolve o uso de vária linguagens secundárias (no mínimo HTML) - mas seu programa se torna algo de uso "real".

Uma forma prática de fazer pequenos programas que usem o webbrowser para exibir a interface gráfica é usando o micro-framework Flask. Ele permite que com a adição de uma linha a mais para decorar suas funções, elas sejam chamadas automaticamente a partir de links ou submissões de formulários em páginas web. Os tutoriais além do [Hello World](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/) vão plugar toda a complexidade necessária para se ter uma app web moderna, "de produção", mas é possível ter uma aplicação que gere uma página simples, com um único formulário e resposta do formulário. Digite `pip install flask`, e você vai ter tudo que é necessário para ter o flask funcionando - aqui tem o "hello world" - mude o HTML para incluir um formulário com os campos que você precisa (com os elementos `<input />` e `<submit />`), e use um if para detectar se o método do *request* é um *POST* para processar o formulário:

```
from flask import Flask
import datetime
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    html = """<h1> Formulário </h1>
    <form method="post" action="#" >

    Entre com a data:
    <input type="text" name="dia" width="2">/
    <input type="text" name="mes" width="2">/
    <input type="text" name="ano" width="4"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>

    """
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = datetime.datetime(

            int(request.form["ano"]),
            int(request.form["mes"]),
            int(request.form["dia"]))
        )
        html = f"""<h1> Você digitou a data {data.isoformat()}</h1>"""

    return html
```

No terminal, no mesma pasta em que esse arquivo estiver, se ele se chamar "teste.py", digite (no windows): `set FLASK_APP=teste.py` e em qualquer outro sistema (Linux, Mac): `export FLASK_APP=teste.py`, e em seguida `flask run`. Abra um navegador no endereço "http://localhost:5000" e use o seu programa.

Para sofisticar a aplicação, conitnue lendo e estudando a documentação do flask - em algum ponto ela ensina como colocar junto os pacotes de front-end web, como "bootstrap", "jquery", e etc... para uma apresentação sofisticada.

- **Aplicação gráfica**

Esse é um outro paradigma que ainda vai ser mais normal apra seus usuários, mas também envolve entender uma série de conceitos diferentes. Embora, na maior parte dos frameworks utilizados, não precise de outra linguagem auxiliar. O Python vem com a biblioteca tkinter, que permite o desenvolvimento de aplicações completas com o paradigma gráfico. Aqui tem um post razoável para entender como fazer: https://www.devmedia.com.br/tkinter-interfaces-graficas-em-python/33956

## Tá, eu li até aqui, mas e se eu **quiser** usar o terminal??

Como descrevi acima, *é possível* criar aplicações desse tipo no terminal. Uma forma de fazer isso que vem embutida no Python é com a biblioteca "curses" - https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/curses.html . Só que, pelos motivos que dei na primeira parte da resposta, a microsoft optou por não evoluir o terminal do windows além do suporte a "print" e "input", então o "curses" do Python não está disponivel por padrão no windows  - a documentação linkada acima tem como contornar isso, mas você vai ver que a coisa se torna bem mais complicada de qualquer forma.

Ao ler a documentação do curses, você vai ver que seu uso é muito, muito mais complexo do que simplesmente fazemos com "print" e "input", mas ainda não muda tanto a ideia de programar como uma aplicação gráfica, ou para web: essas duas formas tem que "responder a eventos" - com curses, seu programa pode continuar sendo linear - isso é, a ideia de 'aqui o programa para para esperar uma entrada do usuário', como fazemos com o input.

Há sim maneiras de se configurar o terminal e alterar a função input para não se precisar de tudo o que o curses oferece, e, com umas duas ou três funções a mais, ter o programa "quase igual" o que era com "print" e "input".  - mas, como dito na sessão acima, é reinventar a roda do terminal de forma que desagrada a todos, inclusive usuários veteranos do terminal. Isso não funcionaria no windows - só em Mac e Linux, e é tão "arcano" e esquecido que é praticamente impossível até fazer uma busca de como fazer (eu tentei).  O que existem são caractéres de controle ANSI - sequências especiais de caracteres impressos que permitem a troca de cor, ou posicionamento do cursor no terminal. (então, depois de um input, você pode mandar o cursor de volta pra linha de cima, e andar um certo número de caracteres pra frente).  A sequência para mandar o cursor pra linha de cima, por exemplo, é "ESC [A" - pode ser escrita em Python como `print("\x1b[A", end="")` - troque o A por "C" para andar o cursor pra frente. A documentação completa dessas sequências está em https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code - mas claro que não recomendo que você escreva seu programa usando as mesmas. Se for realmente ficar no terminal, melhor aprender a usar o curses.

- **tá, mas tem como?**

Sim - via de regra dá, mas sempre vão sobrar "casos de uso" que não são cobertos - se quiser cobrir todos, você acaba tendo que re-escrever o "curses" inteiro.

```
n_input_previous_col = 0

def n_input(prompt='', end='\n'):
    global n_input_previous_col
    result = input(prompt)
    if end.startswith('\n'):
        print(end[1:], end='')
        n_input_previous_col = len(end) - 1
        return result
    positions = n_input_previous_col + len(prompt.split('\n')[-1]) + len(result)
    CSI = '\x1b['
    cursor_up = CSI + 'A'
    cursor_right = '{}{}C'.format(CSI, positions)
    print (cursor_up, cursor_right, sep='', end='')
    n_input_previous_col = positions
    return result
```

A função acima implementa mais ou menos bem o parâmetro "end" para input - basta chama-la no lugar do input normal. Ela faz isso detectando se o "end" for diferente de um que comece com "\n", que o input sempre faz, ela move o cursor de volta uma linha pra cima, e faz um trabalho de adivinhar em qual coluna a digitação parou - movendo o cursor para a direita.

Funciona no Linux e Mac, e em alguns programas de terminal do Windows - para os terminais padrão isso tem que ser ativado - veja aqui: https://superuser.com/questions/413073/windows-console-with-ansi-colors-handling/1050078#1050078 - não sei o Python já não ativa por padrão.

De qualquer forma, usando a função acima, num ipython num terminal com suporte, eu pude fazer isso aqui:

```
In [17]: a = n_input('dia: ', end='');b=n_input('/',end='');c=n_input('/')
dia: 08/10/2018

In [18]: print(a, b, c)
08 10 2018
```

(Uma das limitações dessa função é que um input  que não comece na coluna zero do terminal - mesmo que seja a continuação de outros - tem que saber em que coluna ele começa. Enquanto só a própria "n_input" é usada com o terminal, ela contabiliza a coluna na variável global `n_input_previous_col`, mas se você intercalar as chamadas à mesma com `print` ou outra saída, vai ter que atualizar essa variável)

## Resumindo:

No ponto em que você quer deixar a entrada e saída da sua aplicação mais sofisticada para usuários finais, você tem que abandonar "print" e "input" - e escolher um caminho pra sua jornada. Não tem muito o que fazer.

Comment: Incrível, muito obrigado pela resposta, vai ser de grande ajuda!

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com um exemplo completo de como fazer o input sem quebra de  linha, apesar de toda a explicação de por que não faze-lo.

Comment: Muito obrigado!